# How to find the symmetrical duplicate columns(2 columns) using spark dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below dataframe which has two columns.

Input dataframe:

```
col1,col2
1,2
2,3
7,0
2,1
```

In the above dataframe first row and the fourth row are symmetrical and should be considered only once. We can use either first or the fourth row in the output.

Possible output dataframes.

possibility 1:

```
col1,col2
2,3
7,0
2,1
```

possibility 2:

```
col1,col2
1,2
2,3
7,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `dropDuplicates` on a sorted array column:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "arr", 
    sort_array(array(col("col1"), col("col2")))
).dropDuplicates("arr").drop("arr")

df2.show
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   2|   3|
|   1|   2|
|   7|   0|
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` over window partitionned by `least` and `greatest` values from `col1` and `col2` :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window
  .partitionBy(least($"col1", $"col2"), greatest($"col1", $"col2"))
  .orderBy(lit(null))

val df1 = df
  .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
  .filter("rn = 1")
  .drop("rn")

df1.show
//+----+----+
//|col1|col2|
//+----+----+
//|   2|   3|
//|   1|   2|
//|   7|   0|
//+----+----+
```

You can also partition by a sorted array column :

```
val w = Window
  .partitionBy(array_sort(array($"col1", $"col2")))
  .orderBy(lit(null))
```